# MySQL query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

The following code gives me an error "1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

```
$this->mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION;
      UPDATE Balances
        SET balance={$left}
        WHERE user='{$user}';
      INSERT INTO Bought (user, orderid) VALUES ('{$user}', {$id});
    COMMIT;");
```

I just can't understand why this is happening, because every command if it's used separately from others works perfect.

Comment: Execute each part as a single query when using [query()]((http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)), or use [multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute each part as a single query when using [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), or use [multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)